# Can we move Grid Splitter On Left like we drag it on button click in wpf?

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml

```
    <Grid>
    <StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Button Content="◄" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    <Button Content="►" HorizontalAlignment="Right"  VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    </StackPanel>

    <Grid Height="245">

    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <!--Declaring Label-->
            <DockPanel LastChildFill="False" Background="Yellow">
        <Label Content="Left" Grid.Column="0" DockPanel.Dock="Left" />
    </DockPanel>
    <!--Splitter Code-->
    <GridSplitter HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Column="1" ResizeDirection="Columns" 
                  Background="Black" ResizeBehavior="PreviousAndNext" Width="10"/>
    <!--Declaring Label-->
    <Label Content="Right" Grid.Column="2" Background="Pink"/>
   </Grid>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

I want to drag Grid Splitter on button Click. I tried Double Animation.StoryBoard which works on grid but not grid splitter.

[[[image: Initial Image]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l0aEB.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l0aEB.jpg)

[image: Dragged Left]

[image: Dragged Right]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to resize grid columns, not gridsplitter.

```
private void BtnLeft_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MyGrid.ColumnDefinitions[0].Width = new GridLength(100);
}
```

```
<Grid x:Name="MyGrid">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Label Content="Left" Background="LightBlue" />
    <GridSplitter Grid.Column="1" Width="10" ResizeBehavior="PreviousAndNext" />
    <Label Content="Right" Background="LightGoldenrodYellow" Grid.Column="2" />

    <Button Content="Left"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Click="BtnLeft_Click" />
</Grid>
```